How to solve the building error about gtk Inhibit?
I try a simple application to show a window to display image. Before coding, I install:
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev librsvg2-dev

The OS is ubuntu 20.04.
The tried example code is as follow:
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow, Inhibit};

fn main() {
let application = Application::new(
    Some("com.example.GtkExample"),
    Default::default(),
)

application.connect_activate(|app| {
    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("GTK Inhibit Example")
        .default_width(350)
        .default_height(70)
        .build();

    // Connect the `delete-event` signal to a handler function
    window.connect_delete_event(|win, _| {
        // Ask the user if they really want to close the window
        println!("Window close attempt");

        // Here you could add a confirmation dialog and return `Inhibit(true)` if the user cancels
        // For this example, we'll just inhibit the close action unconditionally
        Inhibit(true) // Prevents the window from closing
    });

    window.show();
});

application.run();
}

The dependency in cargo.toml is:
gtk = "0.18.1"
The build error is:
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow, DrawingArea, Inhibit};
                                                       ^^^^^^^ no `Inhibit` in the root

I try to find the definition of Inhibit in gtk3-rs and gtk4-rs source code on github, but nothing.
How to solve it?
Thanks!

You can't Inhibit is not a part of gtk why do you think otherwise?

@cafce25 I googled the code example for gtk window, and the code I found all use Inhibit(boolean) for the signal handler. To run my example code, what should I do?

Use the official examples instead of random ones which I guess are outdated. If you're starting something new you probably want to use gtk4 as well. The old gtk3 bindings are unmaintaned.

@cafce25 You are right. I check the example code in github and replace Inhibit with glib::Propagation::Proceed. That works.

@passinger you are encouraged to answer your own question if you found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
